# MySQL Query problems and BETWEEN using dates

Tags: mysql

I have the following table and data

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `notas`;
CREATE TABLE `notas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cliente` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_lanc` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_pgto` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `descricao` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor_conta` decimal(13,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor_pago` decimal(13,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pago` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `notas` VALUES ('1', '2', '2016-08-23', null, 'Notas Rodrigo     24/07/2016 até 24/07/2016', '0.000', null, null);
INSERT INTO `notas` VALUES ('2', '2', '2016-08-23', null, 'Notas Rodrigo     24/07/2016 até 24/07/2016', '89.950', null, null);
```

And i have this query

```
SELECT *
FROM notas
WHERE notas.cliente = '2' AND
      notas.data_lanc BETWEEN '2016-01-07' AND '2016-07-24'
```

It should return both records but the query always return empty.
What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You filter on dates between January and July of 2016. But your table data is of August 2016. It is correct that you get no records returned.